# Pick locations with high density in a vector

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, binning

I want to find the expected value of y given x, based on some data. I want really good estimates of the mean y-value at a few particular x-values, but I don't want/need to fit something parametric or do a regression.

Instead, I want to take my observations, bin a bunch of them where I have a lot of x-values in a small range of X, and compute the mean of y.

Is there a clever way to select, say, 6 non-overlapping regions of high density from my vector of x observations?

If so, I'll take the center of each region, grab a bunch of the closest x's (maybe 100 in my real data), and compute the associated mean(y).

Here's some example data:

```
# pick points for high density regions

#xobs<-runif(900)

clustery_obs<-function(x){rnorm(40,x,0.2)}
under_x<-runif(11)
xobs<-sapply(under_x, clustery_obs)
xobs<-xobs[0<xobs&xobs<1]

yfun<-function(x){rnorm(1, mean=(10*x)^2-(30*x)+3, sd=6)}

yobs<-sapply(xobs, yfun)

plot(xobs, yobs)
```

Comment: You could bin your x observations by quantile. The `binr` library has a `bins.quantiles` function for this.

Comment: @RoB, I like that idea. Bin by quantiles, I have a bunch of non-overlapping bins with equal numbers of observations but different widths. Select a few of those bins with the narrowest range in x. I may compare that to a loess fit and see if they are different!